# Merge existing Node server with Angular Universal server code

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

Im using angular 7 and have use CLI to make the server.ts files and all the other necessary files for Angular Universal. Im able to transpile and run the server and everything works. However this was added after the fact and I have a built API and server. How do I merge the two into one
So my new generated server.ts (or server.js when transpiled) and my old server file which has everything set up.

Im confused since the new files generated are hundreds of thousands of lines of code.

Comment: You possibly shouldn't and it would be better to keep them as two different Node servers.

Comment: Is this how most people do it? Its not big issue but Im surprised there is no easy way to have both

Comment: Angular Universal supports integration with Express. It is implemented as an express engine, and there are examples on the internet for adding your own routes. Update your question with source code of what you've tried, and keep your questions specific to problems.

Comment: It's possible to join several Express apps into one, but keeping them separate is totally viable solution and it's easier to maintain. Keep Universal server for statics and mount API as /api endpoint, you will likely want to keep them behind Nginx any way.

Comment: I went with making a separate server for serving the website. thanks @estus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a separate node server to host the website.

Not too big of an inconvenience but I did like the static hosting the website was originally using

As mentioned by estus you *can* have it all on one server but it might become messy.